# Show error message on null return for AWS CLI describe-instances

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I've got a bash script calling for the IPs of various instances based on a parameter from the user. Right now if their query doesn't match the script doesn't return anything at all, not even `null`. I'd love to incorporate some kind of error handling to prompt the user to retry. This could be anything from an inbuilt AWS function to a custom error message, I'm not picky.

My script is as follows;

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

#READ ARGUMENTS PASSED IN - expects stack name
if [ "$#" != 1 ]; then
    echo "Illegal number of parameters.  Expecting 1: stack name"
    exit 1
fi

name=$1

aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[PublicIpAddress,Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value]" --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=${name} --output text
```

If it succeeds I'll get something like

```
00.00.00.000
name-of-instance
```

but if it fails I get nothing.

**Is there a way to prompt the user or otherwise show an error message if an aws describe-instances returns no matches?**

Comment: Does it have a return code that you can use? Try printing `echo $?` after success and the failure commands.

Comment: @Inian I didn't see anything in the describe-instances page. Doesn't mean it doesn't exist, I might have missed something...

Comment: @Inian answered too quickly and didn't see your edit - that does print 0! Is there any way I can turn that into a customized error message?

Comment: Alex: I meant after running the failing command on the command line, type `echo $?` on the command prompt to see what value is getting updatd

Comment: A response code of 0 just means an error didn't occur. It is not an indication of how many results were found.

Comment: `0` on success and `1` for failure?

Comment: @Inian, Mark's correct actually - it's printing 0 if it succeeds, regardless of output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output=`aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[PublicIpAddress,Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value]" --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=${name} --output text`

if [ -n "$output" ]; then
    echo "$output"
else
    echo "No such instance $name exists"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Capture the output into a variable first like so:

```
output=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[PublicIpAddress,Tags[?Key=='Name'].Value]" --filter Name=tag:Name,Values=${name} --output text)
```

Then check the content of `output`. If there is something there just echo it to the screen. If there isn't, show your custom error message.

Comment: That is how I was planning to do eventually, `++`, Now a simple check on variable empty can be used.